# Deleting Only One Row in SQLite Using ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to delete only one row from an SQLite database using a content provider, but my code deletes all rows. Here is what I'm doing:

I'm passing this uri:

> content://appfactory.app.dehleezcafe/category/1

Where the "category" is the table name and "1" is the record to delete.

This is my delete code that I call somewhere:

```
 // Delete category
        this.getContentResolver().delete(
                contentURI,
                null,
                null
        );
```

contentURI equals the uri passed.

Here what happens in the delete method in the ContentProvider class:

```
rowsDeleted = db.delete(CategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
```

This will delete all rows instead of row "1" ?? Which is not what I want. I appreciate any suggestions.

Here is my contract:

```
public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "appfactory.app.dehleezcafe";

public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

public static final String PATH_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String PATH_ITEM = "item";
```

The Category BaseColumns class:

```
public static final class CategoryEntry implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "category";

    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME  = "name";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
            BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_CATEGORY).build();

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
            ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_CATEGORY;

    public static Uri buildCategoryUri(long id) {
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);

    }
}
```

The Item BaseColumns class

```
 public static final class ItemEntry implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "item";

    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "price";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHOTO = "photo";
    // Column with the foreign key into the category table.
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_KEY = "category_id";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
            BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_ITEM).build();

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
            ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_ITEM;

    public static Uri buildItemUri(long id) {
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);

    }
```

Create Statements:

```
 // Category table create statement
final String SQL_CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + CategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +

        CategoryEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        CategoryEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        " )";

 // Item table create statement
final String SQL_CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +

        ItemEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        // the ID of the category entry associated with this item data
        ItemEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_KEY + " INTEGER, " +
        ItemEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        ItemEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        ItemEntry.COLUMN_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        ItemEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO + " BLOB, " +

        // Set up the category column as a foreign key to category table.
        " FOREIGN KEY (" + ItemEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_KEY + ") REFERENCES " +
        CategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + CategoryEntry._ID + ") " +
        " )";

// Constructor
public MenuSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

The delete method in the content provider:

```
// Delete Method
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // Student: Start by getting a writable database
    final SQLiteDatabase db = menuDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Student: Use the uriMatcher to match the WEATHER and LOCATION URI's we are going to
    // handle.  If it doesn't match these, throw an UnsupportedOperationException.
    final int matchVal =  uriMatcher.match(uri);
    int rowsDeleted = 0;

    // This makes delete all rows return the number of rows deleted
    if(selection == null)
        selection = "1";

    switch (matchVal) {
        case ITEM:
            rowsDeleted = db.delete(
                    MenuContract.ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;

        case CATEGORY:
            rowsDeleted = db.delete(
                    MenuContract.CategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;

        case ITEM_WITH_CATEGORY:
            rowsDeleted = db.delete(CategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;

        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);

    }
    // A null value deletes all rows.
    if(rowsDeleted != 0 ) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }

    // Return the actual rows deleted
    return rowsDeleted;
}
```

I could get the cases recognized but with no success in deleting only one row.

**EDIT**

The weird thing is that I'm able to delete specific columns from the "item" table with no problems using this code:

```
  // Delete items of a category
        String[] selctionArg = {String.valueOf(id)};

        this.getContentResolver().delete(
                ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                ItemEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_KEY+"=?",
                selctionArg
                );
```

Using the same code with "category" table isn't deleting anything, and using the code before deletes all rows instead of a specific row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone. I was able to solve the problem. The problem was that I'm passing the row's position in the list view considering it to be the same as row's _id in the SQLite database. This is true only when we first create the listview rows and store them in the database because they match. However, when we delete rows, the listview rows' positions change their values and no longer valid to be passed as item's _id in sqlite in the selection criteria because sqlite item's _id stays the same and isn't affected by the position changes in the listview. To solve this I needed to pass a cursor of the clicked item and extract the item's _id from the cursor.
For simplicity, let's say I want an item to be deleted when clicked:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Somewhere in the category fragment I'm declaring constants for category columns:

```
// These indices are tied to CATEGORY_COLUMNS.  If FORECAST_COLUMNS changes, these
// must change.
static final int COL_CATEGORY_ID = 0;
```

Then I can pass that cursor anywhere to extract the _id of the item you want to delete:

```
@Override
public void deleteItem(Uri contentURI, Cursor cursor) {

    long id = cursor.getLong(CategoryFragment.COL_CATEGORY_ID);

    // Delete items of a category
    String[] selctionArg = {String.valueOf(id)};

    // Delete category
    getContentResolver().delete(
            MenuContract.CategoryEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            MenuContract.CategoryEntry._ID + "=?",
            selctionArg
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this way it is useful

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
int x = db.delete(MenuContract.ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME,
        MenuContract.ItemEntry.ITEM_ID + " = ?",
        new String[]{item_id});
System.out.println("number of rows deleted"+x);
db.close();
```

Comment: Thanks man, it didn't work now it's not deleting anything and as if I'm not pressing delete button

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution for you, try it out!

Note I have made corrections on the `CATEGORY` case. And ya don't forget to replace `_id` with your column name.

```
// Delete Method
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // Student: Start by getting a writable database
    final SQLiteDatabase db = menuDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Student: Use the uriMatcher to match the WEATHER and LOCATION URI's we are going to
    // handle.  If it doesn't match these, throw an UnsupportedOperationException.
    final int matchVal =  uriMatcher.match(uri);
    int rowsDeleted = 0;

    // This makes delete all rows return the number of rows deleted
    if(selection == null)
        selection = "1";

    switch (matchVal) {
        case ITEM:
            rowsDeleted = db.delete(
                    MenuContract.ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;

        case CATEGORY:
            String segmentnew = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                selection = "_id=" + segmentnew;
            } else {
                selection = "_id=" + segmentnew + " AND (" + selection + ")";
            }

            rowsDeleted = db.delete(
                    MenuContract.CategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;

        case ITEM_WITH_CATEGORY:
            rowsDeleted = db.delete(CategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;

        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);

    }
    // A null value deletes all rows.
    if(rowsDeleted != 0 ) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }

    // Return the actual rows deleted
    return rowsDeleted;
}
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Appreciate it, I replace the code you suggested and added CategoryEntry._ID + "="  in place of "_id=", but now it's not deleting anything like nothing is happening.

Comment: @fullMoon are you getting the right value of `segmentnew`? did you debug and check the value?

Comment: Yes segmentnew is returning the row position I want to delete correctly, I don't know why it's not deleting anything and always returns 0 for "rowsDeleted"

Answer (score 0):

`this.getContentResolver().delete(CategoryEntry.CONTENT_URI,CategoryEntry._I‌​D + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});`

use this with your original code

Comment: sorry use `CategoryEntry._ID`

Comment: are you getting the categoryId from `uri.getpathsegments().get(1)` ?

Comment: I used CategoryEntry._ID and yes categoryId returns the correct row I want to delete

Comment: `this.getContentResolver().delete(contentURI,CategoryEntry._ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});`
use this with your original code

Comment: Thanks, I used it and still not deleting any rows from the category table. I'm able to delete specific items from the item table with no problem. See the edit at the end of the question. So weird, I used the same code for both and changed it accordingly, but it deletes in one table and doesn't delete in the other.

Comment: To delete from category table you need to use Content Uri, selection and selection args for category table.